# Why vacuum isolates heat in a vacuum flask, but not in space?

Tags: thermodynamics

This is very likely a stupid question, but why does the vacuum isolate heat in a vacuum (thermos) flask, but still you feel "cold" in space? Shouldn't you feel warm, because the vacuum isolates the heat of you own body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vacuum prevents *conductive heat transfer*, which is the primary mechanism by which hot drink containers lose their heat to their surroundings.

A vacuum is perfectly transparent to *radiative heat transfer* which is the primary mechanism by which things that are glowing hot lose their heat- like stars in space.

Empty space has a temperature which is determined by how much and what kind of radiation is bouncing around in it. Far from any star, that temperature is extremely low, which means that any warm object like a human in a space suit will lose its heat to space by radiation, and eventually assume the same temperature as empty space, causing the human to freeze solid.

Comment: So actually this is more about the very big temperature difference between space and human body versus the difference between hot drink and its surroundings?

Comment: that is certainly one part of it.

Comment: Cooling satellites is actually a big problem.